# jQuery Google Maps Store Locator not loading external script data in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JS, and learning fast! I am trying to feed [jQuery Store Locator](http://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin) with JSON data to map. I have loaded the very example onto my page and it works perfectly. But in the example, the data is loaded from a JSON formatted file on the server:

```
jQuery('#map-container').storeLocator({'dataType': 'json', 'dataLocation': 'location.json'});
```

I am using D3 on my site and it has a great and simple way to pull JSON data into an object (which I am using to populate charts elsewhere on the site). I am trying to use this to pull in the JSON data into the Store Locator:

```
var map_data_url = "/my-php/data.php?var=GOOGMAP&pid=PNR010101";
d3.json(map_data_url, function (error, data) {
   jQuery('#map-container').storeLocator({'dataType': 'json', 'dataLocation': data});
});
```

but this is not working and showing me no errors in inspect. When I execute the script on its own the JSON is returned to the browser OK. Example:

```
[{"id":"INS0000000003","name":"Corona, Linda","lat":"-27.46818730","lng":"153.03021970","address":"71 Eagle Street","city":"Brisbane","sate":"QLD","postcode":"4001","phone":"07 4343 9696","mobile":"0412 563 235"},{"id":"INS0000000006","name":"Flare, Steve","lat":"-33.25491100","lng":"151.51529500","address":"69 The Corso","city":"Gorokan","sate":"NSW","postcode":"2263","phone":"02 9898 1221","mobile":"0404 569 536"}]
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="map-container" style="width:100%;">
   <div id="loc-list">
      <ul id="list"></ul>
   </div>
   <div id="map"  style="border: width=100%;"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to write the JSON to a file prior to reading it into the Store Locator?

Comment: It's hard to fully understand your question, but if I do get the question, then what headers does your PHP file send?  Specifically does it send a `Content-type` of `application/json` ?  I believe jQuery needs that to best understand what it's receiving.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the reply. The PHP script returns exactly what I show in the post. The JSON string it returns is the same as the example.json that comes with the store locator. I think my issue is one of syntax in how to pass it to the Store Locator as the examples I have found show it reading it from a file and not receiving it in an object. Does this make sense?

Comment: Try putting this at the top of your PHP file: `header("Content-type: application/json");`  That might make the file make sense to jQuery. Servers generally auto-apply that to files ending in `.json` but for obv reasons not to those ending in `.php`.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I will try. The file contains some 50+ queries used in data pull for D3 charts today, and it feeds the data in JSON format back to d3.json function OK... does the syntax of how I pass the data to the storelocator look OK?

Comment: I don't know d3, but JS syntax-wise, I see nothing wrong.  The queries for the data shouldn't matter so long as you're not getting a timeout.

Comment: I just checked the JSON example file (example.json) and overwrote it with the output from my script call and it loads OK. It seems it is the way I am passing it to the storelocator that is the issue. Surely I should not have to write it to a file before reading it into the storelocator?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, my script produces json via the command "echo json_encode($data);" where should I be adding your header statement? Thanks!

Comment: Try putting this at the top of your PHP file: `header("Content-type: application/json");`

Comment: Hi Jeremy thanks for the help! It turns out the code was OK and so was the JSON structure... the JQuery Store Locator tool had some params that needed setting before it would function by reading the external JSON input. Thanks again.

Comment: If you found the solution, post it and mark it as the answer to help others in the future.